# Integration's rule property

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

$$\int_{-1}^1g(x)\,\mathrm dx\approx\alpha g(-1)+\beta g''(0)+\gamma g(1)$$

My goal is to find the coefficients $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that this rule is exact for polynomials of the highest possible degree. Now writing:

> $$g(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i x^i,$$
> $$\int_{-1}^{1} g(x) dx=\int_{-1}^1\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac n2\rfloor} a_{2i} x^{2i}dx=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor} \frac{2a_{2i}}{2i+1}$$ and $$g(-1)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i (-1)^i,\; g(1)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i,\;\text{and }g''(0)=2a_2,$$

I should be able to find the coefficients $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, but I can´t find a way to proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried setting $g(x)$ equal to some polynomial?

Comment: I voted to reopen the question since OP has added additional work on the problem.

Comment: Hint: What happen when you try setting $g(x)=1$ (the constant polynomial $1$)?

Comment: What is the highest possible degree of a polynomial?

Comment: @Gonçalo The highest degree of a polynomial for which the approximation turns out to be exact is $3$.

Comment: Use a polynomial basis, for $g$, one after the other, such as $1,x,x^2-1,(x^2-1)x,(x^2-1)x^2,...$ where one or more of the values are zero. This should give an easy linear system.

Comment: @JP Sorry, I just realized my question was stupid. I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For
$$g(x):=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e,$$
$$\begin{align}&\alpha g(-1)+\beta g''(0)+\gamma g(1)-\int_{-1}^1g(x)\,\mathrm dx\\&=\alpha(a-b+c-d+e)+2\beta c+\gamma(a+b+c+d+e)-\left(\frac25a+\frac23c+2e\right)\\
&=a\left(\alpha+\gamma-\frac25\right)+b(\gamma-\alpha)+c\left(\alpha+2\beta+\gamma-\frac23\right)+d(\gamma-\alpha)+e(\alpha+\gamma-2).
\end{align}$$

- For $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\left(1,-\frac23,1\right),$ this quantity is $0$ whenever $a=0.$
- For $a=1$ and $b=c=d=0,$ this function of $e$ cannot be constantly $0$ (whatever the choice of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$).

Therefore, the "highest possible degree" is $3$ and the coefficients are
$$\alpha=\gamma=1,\quad\beta=-\frac23.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since this quadrature rule is linear, you just need to check that it is exact for $g(x) = x^i,  i = 0, \cdots, k$. Since we have two coefficients to determine, we can use $k=2$ and get
$$
\begin{cases}
\alpha + \gamma = 2\\
-\alpha + \gamma = 0\\
\alpha + 2 \beta + \gamma = \frac 23
\end{cases}
$$

This leads to the coefficients mentioned by @AnneBauval. This means that this formula will hold for polynomials with degree $\leq 2$. Testing for $g(x)=x^3$ and for $g(x)=x^4$ we see that it is exact for polynomials with degree $\leq 3$.